# POS client: Could I only open discovery udp port and not open tcp listen port?

Tags: proof-of-stake, clients

As I said on topic, I did set my security group and router rules only open my client's node discovery port to Internet and reject any nodes connect to my node with tcp listening port. Take Prysm as an example, I only allowed udp port 12000 (default udp port for node discovery) and reject tcp port 13000 (default tcp port for listening connections from other node).

As result, my pos client only have outbound peers and have 0 inbound peer. This actually met my expectations, but what puzzles me is that my nodes are now synchronizing blocks normally for a week. I have two questions: 1. is a pos client only have outbound peers fully functioned? 2. After my node establish an outbound connection with others, will they try to make connection to my peer? If they will, should they conclude my node is unreachable and disconnect with my node? In the end, will my node become an 'untrusted' peer and will not have any outbound peers?

After all, I just want to have a "private" full node.